# How can I use A.I/Image Processing to construct mathematical graphs from drawing?

Tags: image-recognition

In physics, there are a lot of graphs, such as 'velocity vs time' , 'time period vs length' and so on.

Let's say I have a sample set of points for a 'velocity vs time' graph. I draw it by hand, rather haphazardly, on a canvas. This drawn graph on the canvas is then provided to the computer. By computer I mean AI.

I want it to sort of beautify my drawn graph, such as straightening the lines, making the curves better, adding the digits on axes and so on. In other words, I want it to give me a better version of my drawn graph which I can readily use in, say, a word document for a report.

a) Is it possible/plausible to do this?
b) Are there any APIs available that can already do this? (Don't want to reinvent the wheel)
c) Any recommendations/suggestions to make the idea possible by altering it somehow?

Comment: All you need is software package,so I would kindly request you to rephrase your question and post it to *SoftwareRecommendationSite* ,According to my analysis inline with *Ai*  ,Firstly.

Comment: All you need is software package,so I would kindly request you to rephrase your question and post it to *SoftwareRecommendationSite* ,According to my analysis inline with *Ai*  ,Firstly.